# Can Neo4J OGM handle loading and saving a sub-graph?

Tags: neo4j, neo4j-ogm

I would like to load a sub-graph from Neo4J database and use OGM for automatic mapping into entities. After that I wish to change content of some of the entities, and finally the entities should be mapped back into an updated sub-graph that should be saved into the database.

For example, given the model in https://neo4j.com/docs/ogm-manual/current/tutorial/: e.g. four "Subjects" are given and the sub-graph of interest contains all "Teacher"s "Class"es and "Student"s, which are related via the selected "Subject"s.

Is it possible to load and save sub-graphs with Neo4J and OGM? Pointers to documentation and examples are welcomed.

Answer (score 1):

The link you've posted is the documentation: https://neo4j.com/docs/ogm-manual/current/tutorial/

Once you've [configured](https://neo4j.com/docs/ogm-manual/current/reference/#reference:configuration) the OGM, obtain a reference to a Session via a [SessionFactory](https://neo4j.com/docs/ogm-manual/current/reference/#reference:connecting) and [load entities](https://neo4j.com/docs/ogm-manual/current/reference/#reference:session:loading-entities) to whatever depth you require using load or query methods. These are mapped by the OGM onto your domain objects. Then, you simply modify them as required, and [persist them](https://neo4j.com/docs/ogm-manual/current/reference/#reference:session:persisting-entities) back to the graph.
The depth controls how many levels of related entities are loaded/saved i.e. the subgraph.

See tutorial code samples here: https://github.com/neo4j-examples/neo4j-ogm-university